# Flutter how to update Listview.builder if scroll down on screen

Tags: flutter

I'm working with a **ListView.builder** in Flutter. For now, all was working fine, but I want to add the ability, if you scroll down the screen, the data will be updated. (i have problems to use RefreshIndicator on this case)

```
                    children: [
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                          child: Text(
                            AppStrings.nextScheduledSession,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                          child: Text(
                            Helper.formatDateTodayTomorrow(
                                    list[0].appointmentTime) ??
                                '',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: greyColor,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        if (list.isNotEmpty)

                          ListView.builder(

                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            itemCount: 1,
                            itemBuilder: (context, int i) {
                              return AppointmentsListItem(
                                appointment: list[i],
                              );
                            },
                          ),

                      ],
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://pub.dev/packages/loading_more_list ?

Comment: i think RefreshIndicator is good

Comment: Use this https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination/example

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html
Pass ScrollController into ListView.builder and listen on change of controller position
Of course this will need some calculations

Answer (score 0):

I have also implemented this on scrollcontroller addListener.

```
double _lastEndOfScroll = 0;

_scrollController.addListener(() {
  double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
  double currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
  if (maxScroll == currentScroll) {
      _lastEndOfScroll = maxScroll;
      fetchData(search.filter);
    }
});
```

In your Listview.builder add itemcount length.

```
       ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _reports?.length ?? 0,
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    itemBuilder:(context, index) {
                      AppointmentsList item = _reports[index];
                      return AppointmentsListItem(
                            appointment: item,
                    },
                  ),
```